# Are morphisms of algebraic varieties determined by their underlying functions?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ringed-spaces

Let $K$ denote an algebraically closed field. Define that an algebraic variety over $K$ is a ringed space that can be covered by open sets, each of which is isomorphic to an affine algebraic variety, possibly subject to some further conditions if it helps.

> **Question.** Let $(f,\alpha) : A \rightarrow B$ and $(f,\beta) : A \rightarrow B$ be two morphisms of locally ringed spaces. Are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ necessarily equal as natural transformations? If not, is this at least true for "nice" spaces and/or "nice" fields? If not, how is it possible to define a function between algebraic varieties and then "prove" that this function is a morphism, when the corresponding natural transformation isn't unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as the following example proves.

**Example.** Let $\mathbb{K}=\overline{\mathbb{Z}_p}$ be the algebraic closure of the field of integer numbers modulo $p\in\mathbb{P}$, and let $X=Y=\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{K}}$ as locally ringed space; considering the following maps of $X$ in itself:
\begin{gather}
O:x\in X\to 0\in X,\\
F:x\in X\to x^p-x\in X;
\end{gather}
one has that as maps $O=F$, but as regular maps $O\neq F$ because $O^{*}$ is the zero endomorphism of $\mathbb{K}[t]$ and $F^{*}$ is the *Frobenius endomorphism* of $\mathbb{K}[t]$. $\triangle$

And if one fixes a continuous map $f:(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\to(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ then the pull-back $f^{*}:\mathcal{O}_Y\to f_{*}\mathcal{O}_X$ is well-defined ever; and if $f^{*}$ is a morphism of sheaves then $(f,f^{*})$ is a morphism of locally ringed spaces.

Comment: Consider $\mathbb{F}_p$ to refer to the field of $p$ elements, since its unambiguous; $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is also used to to the ring of $p$-adic integers.

Comment: Yes, I know; indeed I specify what is $\mathbb{Z}_p$. ;)

Comment: So is it correct to say that each continuous map $f$ between ringed spaces induces a canonical morphism of ringed spaces, namely $(f,f^*)$?

Comment: No, it is not! For example: any permutation of $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{K}}$ with Zariski topology is a continuous map, but not any permutation is a morphism of locally ringed spaces.

Comment: @Armandoj18eos, sorry, I mispoke. What I meant was: is it correct to say that each continuous map $f$ between ringed spaces with the property that $f^*$ is a morphism of sheaves yields morphism of ringed spaces, namely $(f,f^*)$, in a canonical way?

Comment: This is correct! ;)

Comment: @Armandoj18eos, so in the example you give, what would it be? The zero map?

Comment: In my example, I consider the zero map in two different implementation. The idea is: different polynomial can give the same polynomial map; as the example proves.

Comment: But what would be the natural transformation induced by this map?

Comment: Sorry: I don't understand your question; can you repeat it with some other detail?

Comment: Wait why is $O=F$? We don't have $$X^p=X$$ for all $$X \in \overline{\mathbb{F}_P}$$ right..

Comment: @M.Van The monomial $x^p$ is different by $x$; instead, $\alpha^p=\alpha$ for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}_p$. Do you understand the difference?

Comment: @Armandoj18eos your two maps are different on the level of topological spaces. Consider $p=2$ and let $w\in\overline{\Bbb F}_2$ satisfy $w^2+w=1$. Then the point corresponding to $w$ in $\Bbb A^1_{\overline{\Bbb F}_2}$ maps to $w^2-w=1$ under one map, but $0$ under the other.

Comment: In conclusion this solution does not work

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example (I have problems with the other answer given, see my comments below that): take the algebraic closure $k$ of $\mathbb{F}_p$ as your ground field and consider $X= \text{Spec}(k)$. Then any two distinct automorphisms of $k$ give the same map on the level of sets, since $X$  consists of only one point. You can take the frobenius map and the identity map for example.